"Natural density" of a subset of the plane
Consider a measurable subset X of the plane.  A representative example of the sort of thing we're interested in would be something like
$$X = \left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; \middle|\; \lfloor x \rfloor \equiv \lfloor y \rfloor \pmod{2} \right\},$$
the set of all "black squares" if we cover the plane with a checkerboard pattern.
We are interested in a notion of asymptotic density of this set within the plane.

Of course, on its own, this is a hopeless concept, because we could cook up an exhaustion
$$Y_1 \subseteq Y_2  \subseteq \cdots \mathbb{R}^2, \qquad \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Y_i = \mathbb{R}^2$$
such that the asymptotic density
$$\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{\mu(Y_i \cap X)}{\mu(Y_i)}$$
takes on any limit we like between 0 and 1, or such that it's undefined.
However, for something like the positive integers, there is a concept of a "natural density," which is an asymptotic density taken with respect to the usual ordering on the integers.  To what extent can this generalize?

Given a point $p$ in the plane, we can consider the asymptotic density of $X$ in balls centered at $p$,
$$d_p(X) := \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{\mu(B_r(p) \cap X)}{\pi r^2}.$$
With $X$ as in the example above, $d_p(X)$ is going to be $1/2$ regardless of the choice of $p$.
Moreover, for an arbitrary choice of $X$, if $d_p(X)$ exists for some $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then it appears that it exists for all $q \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and moreover has the same value, because for sufficiently large $r$ the non-overlap between $B_r(p)$ and $B_r(q)$ is an arbitrarily small fraction of $\pi r^2$.  So this density is a property of the set itself, which we could write $d(X)$.

Questions:

Does this concept have a name?  Is it used anywhere?
Does this only work with balls, or could I allow a wider class of sets in the exhaustion without changing the notion, e.g. arbitrary convex sets of finite volume?
The above seems like it ought to generalize to a pretty broad class of spaces.  The ingredients we seem to need are that we have a measure compatible with a metric, that the distance between any two points is finite, and that sufficiently large balls almost completely overlap.  Is this, or something similar, a class of spaces that has a name?  It ought to include stuff like connected Riemannian manifolds.


Context: I saw a TikTok video where the plane was tessellated with a colored tile and the video asked whether more of the plane was red, green, or blue.  More of the tile was red, but this leads to the question of whether there's any sense in which this means more of the plane is red.

I think you mean "balls centered at $p$"

@user58697 fixed, thanks

To address the first question, I have seen this sort of limit (possibly with boxes instead of balls) as a definition of "natural density" in $\Bbb R^2$, for sure.

@GregMartin any idea where?  I couldn't find anything with google

One example is the packing density related to sphere packings.
